# Rails 6 yarn libraries do not load on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

I have an issue with yarn on production, for example after adding aos.js i have the following:

```
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';
import AOS from 'aos';

$(window).on('load', function() {
  AOS.init({
   duration: 1000,
   once: true
  });
});
```

It works fine on development, But it doesn't work on production.
And I have the same issue for fontawesome and few other libraries

Comment: Have you runned RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile before the deploy?

Comment: @BrunoGerotto I did it on the server after the deploy, since this was a one time deploy on the server